# super init Sprites doesn't match position

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

a real quick question here. It seems like super init has it's own way anchoring things around. Here is the example.
Below i have super init with sprite frame "image1", and i have "image2" within the init. The problem is, these 2 images will not over-lapse each other as you would thought, it appears that the anchor point of init 'image1' is 0,0 and 0.5,0.5 for "image2" so the lower left edge of "image1" would be over-lapsing with the center of "image2".

```
-(id) initWithSpriteImage
{
    if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:@"image1.png"]))
    {

        CCSprite *image2=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"image2.png"];
    }
    return self;

}
```

any idea how i can solve this beside removing the init sprite?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: What is the purpose of creating the second CCSprite if you don't use it?

Comment: To which node are you adding each as child?

Comment: I am using the second CCSprite, and i am adding the image2 as the child of image1, As LearnCocos2D below, image2 will anchor on the lower left corner of image 1. assume image1 and 2 are both square of the same size, but square2 center itself on lower left edge of square 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming image2 is a child of the image1 sprite, the behavior you see is correct. I wish it were different because it is a really annoying and hard to understand behavior for beginners.

What happens is that child nodes are not centered on their parent's anchorPoint, but on the origin (0,0) of the parent's texture. So each child is centered on their parent's lower-left corner, unless the parent is a non-visual node like CCScene, CCLayer or CCNode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so i assume there is no way to fix this? Also i've posted a question in cocos2d-central regarding mousejoint. it's be great if you could take a look at it. http://cocos2d-central.com/topic/772-get-body-with-b2mousejoint/  have a nice day!